# Dynamic values to another SQL statement

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to combine two SQL queries into a single SELECT query in PostgreSQL?

My requirements are as follows:

```
SELECT id FROM table1;
SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.id;
```

I think I need to pass values of `table1.id` in as some sort of dynamic values (loop values) for use in the SELECT statement executed on `table2`. What is the easiest way to solve this problem, is it possible to do this with stored procedures or functions in PostgreSQL?

Comment: As @ClodoaldoNeto said, what you're looking for here is a simple [INNER JOIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-join.html) clause, plain and simple. Using functions, triggers or even dynamic SQL in this situation would be exuberant overkill (at best) - please don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.id, name
from
    table1 t1
    inner join
    table2 t2 using (id)
where t1.id = 1
```